# how to use Putty （SSH ）to login the linux in Windows

Tags: linux, ssh

I used the Putty to generated the private key and public key 。

1. private key save in the Windows  C：\ssh
2. I was also touch a new file which is called authorized_keys in Linux that
   Path is : /home/su/.ssh/

[image]

anyway ,I have change the file sshd_config (===>sudo **vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config** )

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile      /home/su/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

when I finish set up putty and try to login
it shows me that server refused our key
[image]

and I aslo print out the log (==>**tail -f /var/log/auth.log**)
there is nothing log about the authorized key login action~~~

[image]

does anybody know why?  which part do I have forget to set????

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the default in SSH on most systems is to not allow **root** SSH access. I believe the setting you are looking for is in `sshd_config` and is called `PermitRootLogin`. It is usually commented out - all you need to do is uncomment the relevant line.

Comment: I would however recommend *not* using the root account like this. Rather create a new user and provide it with any required privileges. Allowing root access via SSH means that in the case that anyone is able to get your private key, they will have **full** access to the entire machine instead of just one user.

Comment: @Lix do you mean I need to change the PermitRootLogin vaule or uncomment it ? anyway ,if  someone login the Linux, how could he get the private key which save in my Window PC ? I am so confuse!!!!

Comment: If the `PermitRootLogin` is commented out, it doesn't matter what value it has. So you'll need to uncomment it and set it to `true` (because you **are** logging in with a root account).

Comment: There are many ways that someone could obtain your key, someone might be able to compromise your computer or even steal the entire device in the case of a laptop.

Comment: @Lix it is OK now ，but **PermitRootLogin** is uncomment and is set no。 and it seems that there is something at the end of the line that you can not see on linux in the editor when I vim a new file for  saving the public key  .[link](https://dan.langille.org/2013/06/11/sshd-error-key_read-uudecode-failed/)   there is another post [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/306798/trying-to-do-ssh-authentication-with-key-files-server-refused-our-key)

Comment: @Lix  ,thanks for your reply ,  I have solve follow below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, for security reasons do this one:

1. Make a group or user where you'll add su - rights with visudo
2. Find a line where it says "root ALL=(ALL) ALL" and add a line below:
   "username ALL=(ALL) ALL".

3&4 steps in sshd_config:

3. PermitRootLogin no
4. HostbasedAuthentication no

For keys, I recommend to visit this site: https://www.howtoforge.com/ssh_key_based_logins_putty

Regards

Comment: what does your second point means？ Fine a line in which file？where is the location?  why PermitRootLogin should be no？

Comment: 1. Is your server reachable from the Internet? If yes, then use PRL no because of security reasons, users from outside doesn't know, if there's some account with sudo su - rights.

Comment: i change  the sshd_config which like what you said in 3,4point ,and I have follow all the step in this site :[link](https://www.howtoforge.com/ssh_key_based_logins_putty)  but it doesn't work ,it always let me set the login name and password,

Comment: it seems that there is something at end of the public key which could see in the Linux editor.[link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/306798/trying-to-do-ssh-authentication-with-key-files-server-refused-our-key)